# Select the default Artifact/Bundle to show for '/' in a Virgo/OSGi/Jetty Environment

Tags: jetty, osgi, eclipse-virgo

Sorry if this is a bit noobish, but I've never done Jetty config, let alone in an OSGi environment.

I'm to make a specific URL show `/ui/dcx/` by default.
I have looked at all the config files I've found for Jetty and Virgo and don't see where this default is configured.

It always redirects `http://localhost:9080` to `http://localhost:9080/splash`.
I have even tried removing the splash bundle from the pickup directory, but the redirect still happens.

Does anyone know where the setting for default URL or default bundle is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Virgo server it appears that /pickup/org.eclipse.virgo.apps.splash-3.5.0.RELEASE.jar is bound to contextRoot of '/' (Web-ContextPath: /) and the `welcome-file` element of web.xml is bound to index.html which inturn has a meta refresh for '/splash'.

So to change that to `/ui/dcx/` you would need to remove the splash bundle and have your bundle bound to contextRoot '/' and then in turn follow the same approach as used by the splash bundle.

Comment: I can't get this to work, I set '/" as my Web-ContextPath, I removed org.eclipse.virgo.apps.splash-3.5.0.RELEASE.jar from pickup but when I go to localhost:8080 I always get redirected to localhost:8080/splash. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's working now, haven't touched anything though, it was a matter of restarting the server somehow (although I did restart it earlier too with no results).